# Inserting a value via a variable in json using Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I have to write a specific value using a variable in json. Below is the code.
Instead of price, I need to write a variable that contains the price, can someone instruct how to do this.

```
app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "25.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
};
```

Comment: price: some_value, ...

Comment: or you can use transactions[0].item_list.items[0].price = priceValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable for any value you want.

```
var thePrice = "25.00";

...

"amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": thePrice
        },
```